# SQL query to check whether a meta key is set or not for a post in post_meta table

Tags: sql

Condition: some post have meta_key 'status'. 
Please help me in with this condition:
sql query for those post who don't have meta_key 'status'

Answer (score 1):

Pure SQL questions are off-topic but beyond that, pure SQL is dangerous because it may break if the WordPress Core changes the database structure.

You are better off using Core tools where possible. In this case, [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) can do what you need.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'status',
      'value' => null,
      'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )
  )
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

That will generate this SQL:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
                          AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'status')
WHERE 1=1
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')
  AND (wp_postmeta.post_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0,3
```

Comment: SQL Query please.... I know above part and also the complication. is it really off-topic?

Comment: If you want the SQL just `var_dump($query->request)` and there you have it.

Comment: Due to some req. I have access to DB only...so please help with sql query.

Answer (score -2):

I know old, but I just fixed this!

```
select * from wp_posts
where id not in
(select distinct post_id from wp_postmeta where meta_key='_your_meta_key')
```

note (for efficient downvoters): please read the original posters question that he asked for "sql query", so stop downvoting something just coz you don't understand the questions requirements

Comment: Is this the answer to the original question? Do you not just have added the same answer to some other question?

Comment: yes it is, coz its the "same" query to answer both questions

Comment: i wish you read the query before giving downwote,

Comment: The downvote is there for several reasons. One is that you did not explain a single line or why that should work or why that makes a difference to the other question. Another reason is that this is just a SQL answer and does not take into account that this is running via WordPress DBA Layer.

Comment: i wish you read the original question before this last comment, it specifically said: "sql query for those post who don't have meta_key 'status'" :)

Comment: I wish you had taken the [tour], read the site description and [what is on topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Hint: Plain SQL is not.